# QDomElement::namespaceURI returns empty string

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm trying to get to the root of a problem in some library, and it seems like I don't understand how QDomElement::namespaceURI work, or don't understand how xmlns works.

Here is my minimal isolated code fragment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QDomDocument>

int main() {

    QString request = "<iq from='user2@example.org' id='disco1' to='user1@example.org' type='get'>";
    request +=          "<query node='someAddress' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>";
    request +=        "</iq>";
    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(request);
    QDomElement iq = doc.documentElement();
    QDomElement query = iq.firstChildElement();
    std::cout << query.tagName().toStdString() << " " << query.namespaceURI().toStdString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it this way

```
g++ -o xmlTest xmlTest.cpp -lQt5Core -lQt5Xml -I /usr/include/qt -I /usr/include/qt/QtCore -I /usr/include/qt/QtXml
```

I expect it to print `query http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info`

Instead it prints `query`  and I do not understand why.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default QtXml does not do namespace processing. There is an optional `bool namespaceProcessing` flag you can pass to [`setContent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomdocument.html#setContent) to enable it.

Modifying that line like so, produces the expected behaviour:

```cpp
doc.setContent(request, true);
```

```bash
$ ./xmlTest 
query http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info
```

Comment: Oh my! This, indeed solves it and I didn't know it! Thank you so much!